# split long 2D matrix into the third dimension

Tags: matlab, matrix, multidimensional-array, vectorization

Say I have the following matrix:

```
A = randi(10, [6 3])
     7    10     3
     5     5     7
    10     5     1
     6     5    10
     4     9     1
     4    10     1
```

And I would like to extract each 2 rows and put them into the third dimension, so the result would be like:

```
B(:,:,1) =
     7    10     3
     5     5     7
B(:,:,2) =
    10     5     1
     6     5    10
B(:,:,3) =
     4     9     1
     4    10     1
```

I can obviously do this with a for loop, just wondering how to do it more elegantly as one-liner using **permute**/**reshape**/.. (note matrix size and step must be parameters)

```
% params
step = 5;
r = 15;
c = 3;

% data
A = randi(10, [r c]);
B = zeros(step, c, r/step); % assuming step evenly divides r

% fill
counter = 1;
for i=1:step:r
    B(:,:,counter) = A(i:i+step-1, :);
    counter = counter + 1;
end
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's a one-line solution using [`reshape`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) and [`permute`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html):

```
C = 3;          % Number of columns
R = 6;          % Number of rows
newR = 2;       % New number of rows
A = randi(10, [R C]);  % 6-by-3 array of random integers
B = permute(reshape(A.', [C newR R/newR]), [2 1 3]);
```

This of course requires that `newR` divides evenly into `R`.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks!
BTW how can you index a matrix in row-major instead of column-major (the way MATLAB does) ?

Comment: Linear indexing of MATLAB matrix elements always follows column-major order. If you want to access elements along rows, you have to first transpose the matrix before performing linear indexing. That's why I have `A'` as the first argument to RESHAPE in the above solution. For more info on matrix indexing in MATLAB, check this link: http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/digest/sept01/matrix.html

Answer (score 2):

Here's a one-liner with [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) and [`permute`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html), but without transposing the input array -

```
out = permute(reshape(A,newR,size(A,1)/newR,[]),[1 3 2]);
```

, where `newR` is the number of rows in the  `3D` array output.

---

### Benchmarking

This section compares the proposed aproach in this post against the [`other solution with reshape, permute & transpose`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1390941/3293881) on performance. The datasizes are inflated proportionality to the ones listed in the question. Thus, `A` is `60000 x 300` sized and we would split it such that the `3D` output would have `200 rows` and thus dim-3 would have `300` entries.

Benchmarking code -

```
%// Input
A = randi(10, [60000 300]); %// 2D matrix
newR = 200;                 %// New number of rows

%// Warm up tic/toc.
for k = 1:50000
    tic(); elapsed = toc();
end

N_iter = 5; %// Number of iterations for each approach to run with

disp('---------------------- With PERMUTE, RESHAPE & TRANSPOSE')
tic
for iter = 1:N_iter
    [R,C] = size(A);
    B = permute(reshape(A',[C newR R/newR]),[2 1 3]); %//'
end
toc, clear B R C iter

disp('---------------------- With PERMUTE & RESHAPE')
tic
for iter = 1:N_iter
    out = permute(reshape(A,newR,size(A,1)/newR,[]),[1 3 2]);
end
toc
```

Output -

```
---------------------- With PERMUTE, RESHAPE & TRANSPOSE
Elapsed time is 2.236350 seconds.
---------------------- With PERMUTE & RESHAPE
Elapsed time is 1.049184 seconds.
```