# how to save looping data one by one into excel file in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, xls

I have a huge set of data in Excel file sheet 1. The number of columns is fixed (6) but there are lots of rows.

For every 3 rows, I need to pick out the minimum value of 2nd column and save the whole row into Excel file or sheet 2, how am I going to write the script?

#### item.xls (sheet 1):

```
0.3 0.5 0.1 0.8 0.4 0.6
0.2 0.4 0.9 0.1 0.9 0.4
0.2 0.3 0.1 0.01 0.2 0.5
0.3 0.5 0.1 0.8 0.01 0.2
0.2 0.2 0.9 0.1 0.2 0.4
0.2 0.3 0.1 0.01 0.3 0.5
.......
```

In the first 3 rows, the minimum value of 2nd column is 0.3, then write the whole row into sheet 2 of the Excel file.

Then the next 3 rows, the minimum value of 2nd column is 0.2, then write the whole row into sheet 2 of the Excel file.

The result I would like to get is:

#### item.xls (sheet2):

```
0.2 0.3 0.1 0.01    % 1st 3 rows, the minimum value is 0.3 in 2nd column
0.2 0.2 0.9 0.1     % 2nd set of 3 rows, the minimum value is 0.2 in 2nd column
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will show how to extract the relevant rows from the data in a vectorized manner. I will leave the part of reading/writing excel files to you (it should be straightforward):

```
%# sample data
data = rand(3*10,6);

%# for each three rows, find the min of second column, and get the row index
[r c] = size(data);
d = permute(reshape(data',[c 3 r/3]),[2 1 3]);  %'# split into third dimension
[~,idx] = min(d(:,2,:));                        %# find min of col2
idx = squeeze(idx) + (0:3:(r-1))';              %'# adjust indices

%# extract these rows from the data matrix
result = data(idx,:);
```

Comment: question about [2 1 3]..what does it mean?

Comment: it's not clear from your description whether you want to get the entire rows or simply the first four columns. For the latter, change the last line in my code to: `result = data(idx,1:4);`

Comment: @down: that whole line (with the [2 1 3]) rearranges the elements into a 3D matrix such that each three rows are in one slice. Read this question to understand: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390909/matlab-split-long-2d-matrix-into-the-third-dimension

Answer (score 1):

Down, some clarification on your problem would help to find a better solution.  Based on my interpretation of your question, the following bit may help.  I'm generating random test data here.

```
% the number of test data rows
N = 12;

% generate some random vectors for testing
test1 = rand(N,1);
test2 = rand(N,1);
test3 = rand(N,1);
test4 = rand(N,1);

% create a temporary matrix to store the minimum of every
% 3 row set
final = zeros(N/3,4);

% loop in increments of 3
j = 1;
for k=1:3:N
    tmp = test2(k:k+2);

    % find the index of the minimum in this 3 row group of the 2nd col
    idx = find(tmp<=min(tmp));

    % offset idx to index into the original data properly
    idx = idx+k-1;

    % assign the "row" to the final variable
    final(j,:)=[test1(idx) test2(idx) test3(idx) test4(idx)];
    j = j+1;
end
% write the full results out at once
xlswrite('test.xls',final);
```

Try this out and if it's not quite what you are looking for, post a comment to clarify your question.

Comment: i have edit the question..but the idea is correct..however, i have no idea how to read the data from excel file...the 'final(j,:)=[test1(idx) test2(idx) test3(idx) test4(idx)];' test1(idx) is column 1, how am i to replace it? please advise..thanks..