# MATLAB - re-arrange matrix by vertically concatenating submatrices

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am having trouble with the following task:
Suppose a 3x6 matrix:

A =

```
0.2787    0.2948    0.4635    0.8388    0.0627    0.0435
0.6917    0.1185    0.3660    0.1867    0.2383    0.7577
0.6179    0.7425    0.0448    0.4009    0.9377    0.4821
```

What I would like to do is to divide the matrix into blocks, like this:

A =

```
0.2787    0.2948  |  0.4635    0.8388  |  0.0627    0.0435
0.6917    0.1185  |  0.3660    0.1867  |  0.2383    0.7577
0.6179    0.7425  |  0.0448    0.4009  |  0.9377    0.4821
```

and vertically concatenate these blocks to get the final result:

```
0.2787    0.2948 
0.6917    0.1185  
0.6179    0.7425  
0.4635    0.8388
0.3660    0.1867
0.0448    0.4009
0.0627    0.0435
0.2383    0.7577
0.9377    0.4821
```

I think if I can get help with this, then I can perhaps
do it for arbitrary matrices A. I can solve the above
problem using for-loops, but I am looking for a vectorised solution.

Thanks in advance!
N.

Comment: Look up [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/reshape.html).

Comment: I think it takes more than reshape. I mean reshape combined with some other operation...

Comment: for those interested, here is a related question: [split long 2D matrix into the third dimension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390909/split-long-2d-matrix-into-the-third-dimension)

Comment: @user1438310 Yes, I know. I was mentioning a tool you might not have known about. I would not have mentioned it if you had maybe included something about what you have tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following:

```
A = rand(3,6);
blkSz = 2;

C = mat2cell(A, size(A,1), blkSz*ones(1,size(A,2)/blkSz));
C = cat(1,C{:})
```

This assumes that `size(A,2)` is evenly divisible by `blkSz`

Comment: Thanks, for the reply, it will take me a while to apply your solution to my code, but I will get back to you..

Comment: SO didn't referesh until until after I posted my answer too. :)

Comment: @Amro I'm obligated to upvote yours, and I don't feel bad about being scooped by you.

Answer (score 3):

This works where your matrix is `A` and what you want is `D`

```
C = mat2cell(A,[3],[2 2 2])
D = cat(1,C{:})
```

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to do it **without** `cell2mat`, (only with `reshape`s and `permute`) and thus a lot faster!

You need to use the "3rd dimension". It's similar to what is described in 
[split long 2D matrix into the third dimension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390909/split-long-2d-matrix-into-the-third-dimension).

Here is the solution for the above matrix:

```
A1 = reshape(A, 3, 2, []);  % 3rd dimension is numel(A)/2/3
A2 = permute(A1, [2 1 3]);  % transpose 1st and 2nd dimension
Ans= reshape(A2, 2, [])' ;  % note the transpose
```

For a matrix of this size, the difference in running time is negligible. However, for a large matrix, the difference is more than an order of magnitude:

```
A=rand(3, 2*10000);

%% good method

tic
A1 = reshape(A, 3, 2, []); %3rd dimension is numel(A)/2/3
A2 = permute(A1, [2 1 3]);
A3 = reshape(A2, 2, [])' ; %note the transpose'
toc

%% mat2cell method

tic
blkSz = 2;
C = mat2cell(A, size(A,1), blkSz*ones(1,size(A,2)/blkSz));
B3 = cat(1,C{:});
toc

%% make sure the answer is the same:
assert(max(A3(:)-B3(:))==0)
```

output:

```
>> Elapsed time is 0.001202 seconds.
>> Elapsed time is 0.043115 seconds.
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
width = 2; 
m = length(A(:))/width;
fn = @(i) reshape(A(:, i:width:end), m, 1);
B = cell2mat(arrayfun(fn, 1:width, 'UniformOutput', false));
```

Just specify how many columns you want at a time in the `width` variable.

Answer (score 0):

By concatenating vertically, matrix width divisible by 3 assumed:

```
B = [ A(:,1:(size(A,2)/3)); A(:,size(A,2)/3+1:size(A,2)/3*2); A(:,size(A,2)/3*2+1:end) ];
```