# How to reshape matlab matrices for this example?

Tags: matlab, matrix, reshape

I have a 40x16 matrix or 8 5x16 one below the other i.e. aligned vertically. 
I want to get a 5x128 matrix from that such that I align the 8 5x16 matrices horizontally.
is there an efficient/quicker (rather than the hardcoded for loops) way to do this?

I want the individual 5x16 matrices intact.

Comment: related questions: [split long 2D matrix into the third dimension](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1390909/97160), [MATLAB - re-arrange matrix by vertically concatenating submatrices](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10904579/97160)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. Suppose your matrix is `A` (40x16).

Here's a way using `reshape`:

```
m = 5; n = 8; p = 16;
B = reshape(permute(reshape(A', p, m, n), [2 1 3]), m, n*p);
```

B will have your eight 5x16 matrices next to each other, intact.

And here's a way without `reshape`:

```
m = 5; n = 8;
B = cell2mat(arrayfun(@(i) A(m*(i-1)+1:m*i, :), 1:n, 'UniformOutput', false));
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the `reshape` function: [doc@mathworks](http://www.mathworks.fr/help/techdoc/ref/reshape.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use MAT2CELL to divide the big matrix into smaller ones, then combine along the dimension you want:

```
A = rand(8*5,16);
blkSz = 5;

C = mat2cell(A, blkSz*ones(1,size(A,1)/blkSz), size(A,2));
C = cat(2,C{:})
```

Answer (score 0):

Reshape a 3-by-4 matrix into a 2-by-6 matrix.
A =
    1    4    7    10
    2    5    8    11
    3    6    9    12

B = reshape(A,2,6)

B =
    1    3    5    7    9   11
    2    4    6    8   10   12
B = reshape(A,2,[])

B =
    1    3    5    7    9   11
    2    4    6    8   10   12